# ASP.NET chart control - layout x-axis label with reversed y-axis

Tags: c#, asp.net, layout, charts, asp.net-charts

I have an asp.net chart control with different Series and i have reversed the y-axis. Because of this i had to set Crossing AxisY to Maximum to have the xaxis on the bottom. Without setting the crossing value to maximum i have the xaxis on the top but i want it at the bottom.

The Problem is that the x-axis label are still on top and not at the bottom. Anyone has an idea how to reverse y-axis and have the normal x-axis labels at the bottom?

```
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsReversed = true;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = Double.MaxValue;
```

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution (I may come back later and tell you how to do it with your existing code)
Note: While I am using a winform to demonstrate this, it should work the same in your asp.net application.

In my alternate solution, you could skip the use of this statement

```
//Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = Double.MaxValue;
```

and instead, you could set your dataseries to use the secondary x-axis!

```
//chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = Double.MaxValue; // Disabled - from your example.
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsReversed = true;
chart1.Series[0].XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;

// Example data for image below
chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 0));
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 40));
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 20));
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(4, 90));
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(5, 20));
```

My example code it results in the following picture:

[image: Example]

Should you find my answer adequate please mark as accepted.  Thanks!